# Traducir el plugin Woocommerce en su totalidad

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Buenas chicos, he intentado todo lo posible para poder traducir estas partes de Woocommerce pero todavía no he dado con nada, estas son las partes que quiero traducir al español.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la otra parte :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En la [página de traducciones de WooCommerce](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/stable/es/default) andá hasta abajo de todo, elegí la opción *Machine Object Message Catalog (.mo)* y apretá en el enlace que dice *Export*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez descargado el archivo de traducción, renombralo como `woocommerce-IDIOMA.mo` (por ejemplo, para español de Argentina sería `es_AR`, quedando `woocommerce-es_AR.mo`) y ponelo en `wp-content/language/woocommerce/`.

Si te interesa personalizar la traducción, en la [documentación de WooCommerce (en inglés)](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/#section-8) te indican cómo hacerlo.